# Как разбить строку сразу по нескольким разделителям?

Tags: python, парсер, url

```
import re
s = input().split()
print(re.split('?|&',s))
```

Не получается таким образом, выводит кучу непонятных ошибок.

Нужно разбить строку по знакам: `?` или `&`

Для примера подается какая то URL строка:

```
https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=котики&source=images_drawing
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать паттерн `[&?]`. Но лучше использовать встроенные библиотеки для разбора url-строк. [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), например.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [84]: re.split(r"[?&]", url)
Out[84]: ['https://yandex.ru/images/search', 'text=котики', 'source=images_drawing']
```

но лучше все-таки использовать [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
In [85]: from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, parse_qsl

In [86]: parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
Out[86]: {'text': ['котики'], 'source': ['images_drawing']}

In [89]: parse_qsl(urlparse(url).query)
Out[89]: [('text', 'котики'), ('source', 'images_drawing')]
```

Comment: а как потом обратиться к элементу ключа text во втором варианте?

Comment: @марат, а в чем трудности: `q = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query); q["text"]`? Можете уточнить в вопросе что именно и в каком виде вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: задача такова , что вводится строка и ключ и по ключу нужно получить элемент , вы помогли очень хорошо, в переменную h ввожу ключ и вывожу ответ, немного преобразовав ваш выше комментарий по обращению к элементу через ключ  `print(*q[h])` и в итоге получаю просто `котики`

Comment: @марат, `parse_qs(urlparse(url).query).keys()` - вернет все ключи...